# 400 bad request - @RequestBody with Map<>

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I am unable to send a post request that has map of (key, values).

Map is not working for @RequestBody

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Model Class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
@JsonSerialize
public class Model {
    @JsonProperty("fname")
    private String fname;
    @JsonProperty("lname")
    private String lname;
    private Model(){

    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> method(@RequestBody Map<String, Model> values){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(values);
    }
```

Input :

```
   {
    "key1":{
        "fname":"First Name",
        "lname": "Last Name"
    },
    "key2":{
        "fname":"First Name",
        "lname": "Last Name"
    }

}
```

Output:

```
   {
    "key1":{
        "fname":"First Name",
        "lname": "Last Name"
    },
    "key2":{
        "fname":"First Name",
        "lname": "Last Name"
    }

}
```

Comment: Can the value in value for map be an object instead of string?

Map<String, Object>

Comment: can you let me know the version number.

I have configured jackson json api in message converters.

I am not using @JsonSerialize annotation.

I am trying exactly the same thing and it is not working.

Comment: Jackson version I used is 2.8.7

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved the issue. The objec that needs to be mapped to request body didn't have default constructor. I had overrided one. Jackson  json api needs default constructor. You gave me hope for my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The object that needs to be mapped to request body didn't have default constructor. I had overrided one. Jackson json api needs default constructor.